# Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList. error in apexOutput panel

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I am wondering if there is a way to include two or more fields in an outputPanel tag, as shown below. My output is accounting for two fields, one within the object and the other in a related object (which is a child to the record), I get this message Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Support_a_salad_bar__c'​ when I save.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Test" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Contact">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Member_Schools_Serviced__r}" var="lineItem">
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!lineItem.Term__c = '2017-2018'&& lineItem.School_Term_Progress_Reports_del__r.Support_a_salad_bar__c =FALSE}">
{!lineItem.Name}
</apex:outputPanel></apex:repeat></messaging:htmlEmailBody></messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: If `.School_Term_Progress_Reports_del__r` is a child relationship, then it would be incorrect syntax to get a field from it using dot notation, because it is a list not one sObject.

Comment: formula expressions can only reference relationships that are parents of the object, never children

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to figure it out by creating a formula field to house my criteria and using that one field in the apexOutputPanel to render. This way worked nicely for my use case. Same design, one field.